# Url is change when I am click to the link

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I am Working On Codeigniter 4, I Have Face a problem when I am click menu Url are change

my controller is

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers;

class Pages extends BaseController
{
    public function index($page='Home')
    {

        if(!is_file(APPPATH.'/views/pages/'.$page.'.php')){
                    die;
                    throw new \CodeIgniter\Exceptions\PageNotFoundException($page);
                }

                return view("pages/{$page}");
    }
        public function about($page='About')
    {

        if(!is_file(APPPATH.'/views/pages/'.$page.'.php')){
                    die;
                    throw new \CodeIgniter\Exceptions\PageNotFoundException($page);
                }

                return view("pages/{$page}");
    }

         public function contact($page='Contact')
    {

        if(!is_file(APPPATH.'/views/pages/'.$page.'.php')){
                    die;
                    throw new \CodeIgniter\Exceptions\PageNotFoundException($page);
                }

                return view("pages/{$page}");
    }

}
```

My Route page

```
$routes->get(':/', 'Pages::index');
$routes->get(':/', 'Pages::about');
$routes->get(':/', 'Pages::contact');
```

and html is

```
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="pages/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
```

initialy it will work fine but when i am click again in menu its url change http://localhost/pages/contact to like this url http://localhost/pages/pages/contact 
i dont know where am i wrong please suggest me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change to absolute path

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="/pages/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/pages/about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/pages/contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```